# How to record audio output with python-sounddevice?

Tags: python, audio-streaming, python-sounddevice

I am trying to repurpose the example that records arbitrary length microphone audio to capture audio output https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.4.1/examples.html#recording-with-arbitrary-duration

I am not sure how to setup the device correctly and whether I can actually capture the output sound with python-sounddevice

Comment: What do you mean by "capture audio output"?  You can't record what's being sent to the speaker.  Is that what you're after?

Comment: It seems there are ways to capture what is sent to the speaker such as https://github.com/ExistentialAudio/BlackHole

Comment: That's a different question.  It solves the problem, but it is intrusive.  You have to change your apps to send through the virtual speaker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into it more it seems like I need to use a virtual audio driver to capture output such as https://github.com/ExistentialAudio/BlackHole for Mac or pulseaudio can be setup to do this on Ubuntu then I can connect to the virtual audio driver which can capture the output and then write it out